# Remove Equal Sign "=" from GET request

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which gets the URL parameter after the ? and displays it.

```
<?php

  $qt = http_build_query($_GET);

  echo $qt;

?>
```

But the problem i am having is that, whenever the URL is as follows:
http://example.net/blog?123

The output is as follows:
123=

How can i get rid of that "=" sign? I am parsing this into a mysql db, so the equal sign is not necessary.

Thank you!

P.S: I know that i need to sanitize the requests for security reasons, and i have that covered.

Comment: just replace `=` with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you all! I found the answer by @NaijaProgrammer

Comment: Note that you should take a good look at what you really need. Right now your url is sending a key without a value to the server. If this key is supposed to be your value, you might be better of using url rewriting to rewrite something like `blog/123` to `blog.php?id=123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str_replace:

```
$qt = str_replace("=", "", http_build_query($_GET));
```

Comment: Thank you! I heard $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] does the same job as $_GET. Is there any preference of using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] over $_GET?

Comment: Note that this will break completely if there is more than one query variable.

Comment: Personally, I cannot say if one is preferable to the other. I think `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains more than just the value for one variable the way `$_GET['variable_name']` would return. That being said, you see `$_GET` used most times over `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, it's also less typing.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, try to mark it as the accepted answer so someone else facing similar problem might benefit from it.

Comment: I have a problem though, when i parse this into the database, it doesnt parse in the actual value. It always puts in "0". Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
str_replace("=", "", $qt);
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer by @NaijaProgrammer